# Vector space of symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that the set $V$ of **all** symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices is a vector space?
And what about the dimension of $V$ and its basis consisting of invertible matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm we cannot answer direct Hw questions here. Let's start thinking about what $A+B$ will mean here. About the dimension: how many numbers you think are needed to define a symmetric $2\times 2 $ matrix?

Comment: I know that symmetric means of the form {[a, b];[b, a]}. I need two matrices {[1, 0];[0, 1]} and {[0, 1];[1, 0]}, dimension could be 2.

Comment: is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$ a symmetric matrix?

Comment: no, because $A^T \neq A$

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}^\top = \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: And now is sufficient to prove all 8 axioms of vector space?

Comment: not quite sufficient, but a good start